# Can ‘red’ in ‘red color’ be an adjective?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Can ‘red’ in ‘red color’ be an adjective?

1. Red (adjective) color (noun)
2. Red (noun) color (noun)

Comment: It is *only* an adjective, unless you are referring to "The Reds" (which might mean the Cincinnati baseball team, or a group of Communists, or perhaps a certain political party)

Comment: Red is a good color to paint the kitchen. red=noun. The red doll is mine. = adjective. The color red is not my favorite. Noun. The red color in that painting is awful. color red and red color both have nouns functioning like adjectives.

Comment: @randomhead Why cannot red (noun) color (noun) be?

Comment: @Lambie I think so but randomhead thinks it’s just an adjective.

Comment: All the colors are **nouns** and **adjectives**, shiver my timers.  "Song: Black, black, black is the color, of my true love's hair". Roses are red, violets are blue, yellow's an adjective and a noun it is too. randomhead needs a more colorful life. [Say: why can't x....:)]